# Why is my object properly removed from a list when __eq__ isn't being called?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have the following code, which is making me scratch my head -

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

def eq(self, other):
    print('comparing {} to {} ({})'.format(self.name, 
        other.name, 
        self.name == other.name))

    return self.name == other.name

Element.__eq__ = eq
elements = [
    Element('a'), 
    Element('b'), 
    Element('c'), 
    Element('d')    
]

print('before {}'.format(elements))
elements.remove(elements[3])
print('after {}'.format(elements))
```

Which yields the following output -

```
before [a, b, c, d]
comparing a to d (False)
comparing b to d (False)
comparing c to d (False)
after [a, b, c]
```

Why isn't `eq()` outputting `comparing d to d (True)`?

The reason I'm monkey patching `__eq__` instead of simply implementing it in my `Element` class is because I'm testing how monkey patching works before I implement it with one of the libraries I'm using.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fourth element is the exactly same object with the object the code is passing (`elements[3]`).

In other word,

```
>>> elements[3] is elements[3]
True
>>> elements[3] == elements[3]
True
```

So, no need to check the equality because they(?) are identical (same) one.

Equality check will happen if they are not identical. For example, `__eq__` will be called if the code passes another object with the same value:

```
elements.remove(Element('d'))
```

Answer (score 9):

Python's [`list.remove()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/17e1af9ad66c/Objects/listobject.c#l2337) method first checks whether the both objects are identical otherwise falls back to regular comparison methods like `__eq__` in this case. So, in this case as both objects are identical it is removed from the list.

```
listremove(PyListObject *self, PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < Py_SIZE(self); i++) {
        int cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(self->ob_item[i], v, Py_EQ);
        ...
```

Here [`PyObject_RichCompareBool(PyObject *o1, PyObject *o2, int opid)`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/object.html#PyObject_RichCompareBool) is being used for comparison, and from its docs:

> If `o1` and `o2` are the same object, `PyObject_RichCompareBool()` will
>   always return `1` for `Py_EQ` and `0` for `Py_NE`.

Comment: Thanks for posting a snippet of Python's actual implementation source code. I should really learn to look there for my answers.